# Não consigo fazer um setOnItemClickListenner com um Long (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, firebase

Tenho uma classe Pessoa com o atributo "codigo" tipo Long. Estou com um erro nesse bloco de código. Codigo1 foi onde peguei o ID.

```
 list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            pessoaSelecionada = (Pessoa) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            codigo1.setText(pessoaSelecionada.getCodigo()); // O erro está aqui, tentei usar o Long.parseLong antes do pessoaSelecionada e não deu certo.


            cnpj1.setText(pessoaSelecionada.getCnpj());
            razao1.setText(pessoaSelecionada.getRazao());
            latitude1.setText(pessoaSelecionada.getLatitude());
            longitude1.setText(pessoaSelecionada.getLongitude());

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

O seu problema deve estar no retorno do seu método *pessoaSelecionada.getCodigo()*. Ele está retornando um valor long, no seu caso. Tente fazer isso:

```
codigo1.setText(String.valueOf(pessoaSelecionada.getCodigo()));
```

O método **setText** precisa receber uma string, por isso que seu código dá erro.
Essa questão aqui do *String.valueOf()* também deve ser adicionada nos outros métodos que retornam números, para que funcione corretamente.

Comment: Coloquei esse código, compilou sem problemas, quando abro a activity que está esse código, ela fecha do nada. Como se o código estivesse com algum bug. Ai quando altero o atributo Long na classe Pessoa para String e faço igual os outros, dá certo. Somente quando mudo pro Long dá esse problema. Teria alguma coisa a mais que possa ser feito?

Comment: @Matheus por acaso você está sempre atribuindo um valor para esse atributo, mesmo que seja zero, na sua classe? Porquê se não estiver pode ser esse o problema...

Comment: Talvez, se a sua questão for muito urgente, seja melhor deixar o campo como String e quando for precisar do valor numeral, fazer a conversão para Long. Aí vc deixa essa questão pra ser resolvida quando estiver com mais calma.

Comment: Não atribuí nenhuma valor pro Long não, até porque o usuario que vai colocar o valor, no caso tenho que atribuir mesmo assim? Seria algo do tipo Long codigo = 0; ?

Comment: private EditText cnpj1,razao1, latitude1, longitude1,codigo1; Assim está na minha MainActivity, como o codigo é pego pelo editText, defini ele junto com todas as outras.

Comment: p.setCodigo(Long.parseLong(codigo1.getText().toString())); // Fiz desse jeito pra inserir os dados no firebase, está dentro do bloco de inserção.
O que estou com problemas pelo jeito e na hora de retornar esse dado numa listView,